# How do I declare a class in C# so that I can chain methods?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a custom class that I use to build table strings. I would like to rewrite the code so that I can chain the operators. Something like:

```
myObject
  .addTableCellwithCheckbox("chkIsStudent", isUnchecked, isWithoutLabel)
  .addTableCellwithTextbox("tbStudentName", isEditable) etc.
```

So it seems like I would have each of these methods(functions) return the object itself so that I can then call another method(function) on the resulting object, but I can't figure out how to get a c# class to refer to itself.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you would create a fluent interface like this:

```
class FluentTable 
{
  //as a dumb example I'm using a list
  //use whatever structure you need to store your items
  List<string> myTables = new List<string>();

  public FluentTable addTableCellwithCheckbox(string chk, bool isUnchecked, 
                                                        bool  isWithoutLabel)
  {
    this.myTables.Add(chk);
    //store other properties somewhere
    return this;
  }

  public FluentTable addTableCellwithTextbox(string name, bool isEditable)
  {
    this.myTables.Add(name);
    //store other properties somewhere
    return this;
  }
  public static FluentTable New()
  {
    return new FluentTable();
  }
}
```

Now you could use it like this:

```
  FluentTable tbl = FluentTable
                    .New()
                    .addTableCellwithCheckbox("chkIsStudent", true, false)
                    .addTableCellwithTextbox("tbStudentName", false);
```

This should give you a basic idea of how you need to go about it. See [fluent interfaces on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.23).

A more correct way to do it would be to *implement* a fluent interface:

```
interface IFluentTable
{
 IFluentTable addTableCellwithCheckbox(string chk, bool isUnchecked, 
                                                        bool  isWithoutLabel)
 IFluentTable addTableCellwithTextbox(string name, bool isEditable)
 //maybe you could add the static factory method New() here also 
}
```

And then implement it : `class FluentTable : IFluentTable {}`

Comment: all the answers were good, but this one really goes beyond,  Thanks this was really helpful

Answer (score 7):

Use the `this` keyword as the return value, that way you return itself and you can chain forever:

```
ClassName foo()
{
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This notation is called [Fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.23).

For your example, the simplest form would be

```
public class MyObject {
    public MyObject addTableCellwithCheckbox(...) { 
        ... 
        return this;
    }
    public MyObject addTableCellwithTextbox(...) {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

In the more beautiful form, you declare interfaces (for example, IMyObject) with these methods, and have the MyObject class implement that interface. The return type must be the interface, as illustrated in the Wikipedia example above.

If the source code of the class is not accessible, you can also implement an extension class in a similar way.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you close.

```
public class SomeObject
{ 
    public SomeObject AddTableCellWithCheckbox(string cellName, bool isChecked)
    {
        // Do your add.

        return this;
    }
}
```

Good luck,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that each method returns an interface that declares methods that you want to call on your chain.

EX public IAdd Add()

This way if IAdd defined an add method you can call Add after Add after Add. You can obviously add otterh methods to the same interface as well. 
This is typically called a fluent API

Comment: With this approach you can use several classes to implement your various functions